# cURL Requested URL /api/process.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, curl, ssl-certificate

I created an API for customers using cURL. I just moved to a new server this domain and now the api doesnt not work. Everything seems to be working fine modules wise but I can't get it to work:

This is the response I get.

```
Array ( 
[url] => https://www.1800pay.com/api/process.php 
[content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
[http_code] => 404 
[header_size] => 179 
[request_size] => 506 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.038607 
[namelookup_time] => 0.002688 
[connect_time] => 0.002737 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.038372 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 294 
[speed_download] => 7615 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 294 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.038597 
[redirect_time] => 0 )
Curl error:

Not Found

The requested URL /api/process.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.1800pay.com Port 443
```

CODE USED:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.1800pay.com/api/process.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output_transaction);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

if (!($data = curl_exec($ch))) {print_r(curl_error($ch));echo "error";
return ERROR;
}
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

Thanks for the help :)
And YES THE FILE EXISTS ON THE SERVER..... :|

Comment: Curl is trying 44? Or did you miss a 3 when copy-pasting?

Comment: paste pb i'll fix that thanks

Comment: Is 1800pay.com resolving to the proper IP? You've got SSL verification disabled, so you could be connecting to pretty much ANY server. As well, check the server's error log, it'll state what directory it's trying to check for the process.php file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is within the response.. a not found error is exactly that. Just make sure the file  api/process.php exists on the new domain.

Comment: Thanks but the file is on the server and located where the code mentions :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is but when I try to curl the URL using this:

```
function curl_get($url)
    {
        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $co.":".$apikey);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, FALSE);
        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        $error = curl_error($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        //if (empty($buffer)) 
            //echo "No response from server: ".$error;
        //else 

        return $buffer;
    }
```

I get this:

> Error [Code:1043] Payment ()Key - incorrect data

Comment: yes that's normal because I didn't give you the API key above it has account information. But if you got that answer it means the API works and finds the file but running that PHP script on the server itself does not work. Interesting.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the HEADER, 0 clause?

Comment: is your output_transaction an associative array?

Comment: I'll be back at 4.30pm PST I'll answer then thks

Comment: Yeah I realized I had configured the fnc.ini file incorrectly I had set the domain to 1800pay.com instead of https://www.1800pay.com and for some reason that screwed everything up.